# How to pass value to a Html label into php?

Tags: php

I have am trying to pass the value of a label into the php.

how should i do that?
My HTML looks like:

```
<form action='unsubscribe.php' method='get'>
  <label for='zee@server.com'>zee@server.com</label>
  <input type='submit' value='Unsubscribe me'>
</form>
```

How can i get the value of this label passed into my unsubscribe.php?

Best
Zeeshan

Comment: Is that valid to have the labels for attribute set to an email address instead of an input element?

Comment: No. The for attribute must match the id of a form control (so an input, select, textarea, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the `<input type="hidden" ... />` tag:

```
<form action='unsubscribe.php' method='get'>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="zee@server.com" />
<input type='submit' value='Unsubscribe me'>
</form>
```

If you are going to use `<form method="get" ...>` you might as well just make a url:

```
<a href="http://www.example.org/unsubscribe.php?email=zee%40example.org">Unsubscribe</a>
```

Or with php (note the [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode)):

```
print("<a href=\"http://www.example.org/unsubscribe.php?email=".urlencode("zee@example.org")."\">Unsubscribe</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a hidden input, then use JavaScript to populate the hidden input prior to posting the form so that `unsubscribe.php` can retrieve it via `$_POST`.

Comment: I need to actually answer the question before I edit it :P
Nice answer +1

Comment: i can not use javascript here. because this html is being open in outlook .. i am sending a mail for this. 

but is it possible to disable the input box and then submit its value to php??

Answer (score 0):

Why not when composing the link for the e-mail, append the e-mail address you're sending it to in the unsubscribe url?

```
<a href="http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?email=youremail@mail.com">Unsubscribe Me!</a>
```